# Convert Counters to Hash Table with Linked List values

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, nltk, tokenize

I have 3 counters with total count for word frequency on different strings.

```
Counter({u'childhood': 3, u'waiting': 2}) #counter1
Counter({u'childhood': 5}) #counter2
Counter({u'waiting': 2}) #counter 3
```

Atm I am able to perform counter addition to get the total word count for all words in all counters.

```
Counter({u'childhood': 8, u'waiting': 4})
```

I however need to take each counter and insert them on a hash table with the word as key and a linked list as value where each linked entry has the count per string per Counter.

Example

```
[childhood] : [1,3] -> [2,5] #counter 1 - 3 times | counter 2 - 5 times
[waiting] : [1,3] -> [3,2]
```

How do I achieve this in Python? I was thinking of a dictionary with a deque inside? Or extend the counter addition function?

I'n trying to use existent python data structures without extending or creating custom data structure implementations.

Comment: I think you need to backtrack a little. How did you end up with multiple counters? Wouldn't it be easier to get the counts into the indexed dictionaries you want before producing the intermediate list of counters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some sequence `counters`

```
total = sum(counters, Counter())

table = {word: [counter[word] for counter in counters] for word in total}
```

will give you a dictionary like

```
{
 'childhood': [3, 5, 0],
 'waiting': [2, 0, 2]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `defaultdict(list)` to store each of the entries as a tuple:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

counters = [
    Counter({u'childhood': 3, u'waiting': 2}), #counter1
    Counter({u'childhood': 5}),                #counter2
    Counter({u'waiting': 2})]                  #counter3    

combined = defaultdict(list)

for number, counter in enumerate(counters, start=1):
    for word, count in counter.items():
        combined[word].append((number, count))

print(combined['childhood'])
print(combined['waiting'])
```

Which would give you:

```
[(1, 3), (2, 5)]
[(1, 2), (3, 2)]
```